# cannot insert new XML node with DOM parser

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I've encountered with a strange issue

shortly, here is the XML that I'd like to add a new `person` node

```
<persons>
<person name="name1" surname="surname1" /> 
<person name="name2" surname="surname2" /> 
<person name="name3" surname="surname3" /> 
<person name="name4" surname="surname4" /> 
<person name="name5" surname="surname5" />
</persons>
```

Here is my Android code:

```
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(personsFile);                   
                    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                    Element persons = doc.getDocumentElement();

                    Element personNode = doc.createElement("person");                       

                    personNode.setAttribute("name", "name6");                       
                    personNode.setAttribute("surname", "surname6");

                    persons.appendChild(personNode);

                    Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(personsFile);
                    tf.transform(source, result);
```

But the new node is not inserted completely, 
I receive this

```
<persons>
<person name="name1" surname="surname1" /> 
<person name="name2" surname="surname2" /> 
<person name="name3" surname="surname3" /> 
<person name="name4" surname="surname4" /> 
<person name="name5" surname="surname5" />
<person na
```

For this version of code (no attributes set):

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(personsFile);                   
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            Element persons = doc.getDocumentElement();

            Element personNode = doc.createElement("person");                       

            //personNode.setAttribute("name", "name6");                       
            //personNode.setAttribute("surname", "surname6");

            persons.appendChild(personNode);

            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(personsFile);
            tf.transform(source, result);
```

I receive the following XML

```
<persons>
<person name="name1" surname="surname1" /> 
<person name="name2" surname="surname2" /> 
<person name="name3" surname="surname3" /> 
<person name="name4" surname="surname4" /> 
<person name="name5" surname="surname5" />
<person/><
```

i.e. just like in the first case, it can't save beyond a certain border,

I can't understand the issue, 
On the pad I used previously, this perfectly worked, now I'm using Sony Xperia

EDIT. Tried to save into another (new) XML file and it worked, but still can't understand why the DOM tree is not saved into the original file completely

EDIT2. What the heck. when I rename the new (valid) XML file back into original file, it becomes corrupted just like the original file did. I'm totally frustrated

Comment: Looks like a stream flushing problem, try flushing the out stream explicitly and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the file itself was OK and all necessary nodes were properly written into XML. Surprisingly the file looks corrupted when opened in Windows 7 file explorer and that's really misleading. When I opened the file inside the pad using Android's own text viewer, it showed up all nodes correctly (the file itself is on external storage, so it is (or at least, is supposed to be) browsable in Windows).
The file was actually created in Windows 7 first, and then moved into tab's external storage, so in this case, I guess, Windows somehow keeps the size of the file's original container and does not reflect any changes made to the file beyond that size

PS. Another confusing feature of Sony Xperia is that some files and folders on external storage are not shown in Windows file explorer, including those that were explicitly created by user in Android's file explorer. So if I create file/folder in Android's file explorer, it's going to be hidden in Windows file explorer. Vice versa is not true though